# pass a class as a parameter to a method in a different class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am new to python and I have a project that is asking for building a shopping cart. it has a specific requirement that I should go with. I am stuck with the idea of make add method and remove. 
How can I use a class as a parameter to a method and why?

Here is how my ItemToPurchase looks like

```
class ItemToPurchase:
    def __init__(self, item_name, item_price, item_quantity, item_description):
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_price = item_price
        self.item_quantity = int(item_quantity)
        self.item_description = item_description

    def print_item_cost(self):
        if self.item_price <=0:
            raise ValueError('Invaild price')
        price_for_quntatity = self.item_price * self.item_quantity
        print('%s %d @ %d = %d'%(self.item_name, self.item_quantity, self.item_price, price_for_quntatity ))
    def __str__(self):
        return ('%s'%(self.item_description))
```

and I am stuck with the Shopping cart method and here are the requirements
Parameterized constructor which takes the customer name and date as parameters

- Attributes

  - customer_name (string)
  - current_date (string)
  - cart_items (list)
- Methods

  - **add_item()** - Adds an item to cart_items list. Has parameter ItemToPurchase. Does not return
    anything.
  - **remove_item()** - Removes item from cart_items list. Has a string (an item's name) parameter. Does not
    return anything.
  - If item name cannot be found, output this message: *Item not found in cart.
    Nothing removed.* Using exception

Answer (score 0):

You do not add a `class` as parameter. A `class` is the *shape* and *defined actions* on data.

To your cart you give 'instances' of `ItemToPurchase` - concrete objects filled with data - not the "shape".

```
import datetime as dt        # for the date when creating a cart with name/date

# create an instance of a ShoppingCart with name and date
cart = ShoppingCart("Fred",dt.datetime.now()) 

# create an instance of a ItemToPurchase
item = ItemToPurchase("gum", 2.5, 10, "best tasting chewing gum **ever**")

# and put it into the ShopphingCart instance by using its method add_item()
cart.add_item(item)

# or create the ItemToPurchase-instance on-the-fly, without naming it explicitly

cart.add_item( ItemToPurchase("bubb", 0.5, 3, "best tasting bubble gum **never**") )

# add_item() adds to Carts self.interalItemList
# remove_item() removes from Carts self.interalItemList - eventually only
#     subtracting from an item (10 shoes in, remove 8 shoes, 2 left) etc.
```

---

Sample for instance usage  and classes:

```
class Fruit:
    """POCO for a fruit with a name and size"""
    def __init__(self, name, size):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
    # TODO: needs some more __xxxx__ implemented

class FruitBasket:
    """Basket for fruits, has a finite size."""
    def __init__(self,size= 10):
        self.size = size
        self.fruitsInIt = []

    def addFruit(self, fruit:Fruit):
        """Add a fruit if size fits, prints output for added/not added."""
        currSize = sum( x.size for x in self.fruitsInIt)
        if currSize+fruit.size > self.size:
            print("Can not fit {} size {} in, its too big. Remaining space: {}"
                  .format(fruit.name, fruit.size, self.size-currSize))
        else:
            print("Putting {} in. Remaining space: {}".format(fruit.name, self.size-currSize-fruit.size))
            self.fruitsInIt.append(fruit)

    def view(self):
        """Print all fruits with sizes"""
        for f in self.fruitsInIt:
            print(f.name, f.size)

    def eatAll(self,fruitName:str):
        """If present, eat all fruits of given name, else print message"""
        if not fruitName in [x.name for x in self.fruitsInIt]:
            print("No {} left :((".format(fruitName))
            return
        for f in self.fruitsInIt:
            if f.name == fruitName:
                print("Eating {} of size {}.".format(f.name, f.size))
            else:
                print("Do not like {}.".format(f.name))

        self.fruitsInIt = [x for x in self.fruitsInIt if x.name != fruitName]

import random # for random data


fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Melon", "Banana"]

b = FruitBasket(12) # instance of basket with size 12
for _ in range(10): # try to add 10 random fruits
    b.addFruit(Fruit(random.choice(fruits), random.randint(1,3)))

b.view()    # show basket
b.eatAll("Apple")   # eat all apples (if any in)
b.view()    # show basket again
```

Output:

```
# adding things to basket
Putting Banana in. Remaining space: 10
Putting Melon in. Remaining space: 9
Putting Banana in. Remaining space: 6
Putting Orange in. Remaining space: 5
Putting Melon in. Remaining space: 2
Can not fit Melon size 3 in, its too big. Remaining space: 2
Putting Melon in. Remaining space: 1
Can not fit Melon size 3 in, its too big. Remaining space: 1
Can not fit Melon size 3 in, its too big. Remaining space: 1
Can not fit Apple size 3 in, its too big. Remaining space: 1

# viewing basket
Banana 2
Melon 1
Banana 3
Orange 1
Melon 3
Melon 1

# eatAll  apples
No Apple left :((

# view basket again
Banana 2
Melon 1
Banana 3
Orange 1
Melon 3
Melon 1
```

Comment: but it is said that add_item() which is a method inside a ShoppingCart class will take ItemToPurchase as a parameter and ItemToPurchase is a class. plus all those classes are in the same file so I don't need import

Comment: @MariamAdel  You do not need an import for `datetime` module? Python is not strongly typed. you can create `add_item(self, blablubb):  ... ` to `ShoppingCart - `blablubb` simply being the _name_ that the given paramerter has when using it inside that function. Then you put a concrete ItemToPurchase-object in it when calling it ...

Answer (score -1):

**Check this out might fulfill what you want:-**

```
import datetime
class Customer_name:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.cust_name = name
        self.time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        self.item_list = []

    def add_item(self,item_name, item_price, item_quantity, item_description):
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_price = item_price
        self.item_quantity = int(item_quantity)
        self.item_description = item_description
        self.item_list.append(([self.item_name,self.item_price,self.item_quantity,self.item_description]))

    def remove_item(self,check_item):
        for item in self.item_list:
            if check_item in item:
                self.item_list.remove(item)
                return   

    @property
    def cart_items(self):
        return self.item_list 

    @property
    def print_item_cost(self):
        if self.item_price <=0:
            raise ValueError('Invaild price')
        price_for_quntatity = self.item_price * self.item_quantity
        return ('Cust Name:{} {} {}@{}= {} date {}'.format(self.cust_name,self.item_name, self.item_quantity, self.item_price,price_for_quntatity,self.time ))


a = Customer_name("John")
a.add_item('apple',20,10,"good for health")
a.add_item("Mango",50,30,"tasty")
a.add_item("Guava",50,30,"tasty")
a.add_item("Orange",50,30,"tasty")
a.remove_item("Mango")
print(a.cart_items)
print(a.print_item_cost)
```

Comment: why is your class named `customer_name` - Classes start capital and its a `ShoppingCart`. Why has your `customer_name` attributes that belong to _one_ `ItemToPurchase` ? Why aren't you using `ItemToPurchase` at all?